# Insert image in database (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

At the moment of wanting to insert data of a form to the database it does everything well but the problem is that it inserts all the fields less the image

form view:

```
<form name="form_cot" action="<?php echo base_url("article/insert")?>" method="POST">

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for ="tipotrabajo">Tipo de Trabajo: </label>
 <input type="radio" name="tipotrab" value="0" required> Fabricación
 <input type="radio" name="tipotrab" value="1"> Reparación
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <label for ="origenmat">Origen del Material: </label>
 <input type="radio" name="origenmat" value="0" required> Empresa
 <input type="radio" name="origenmat" value="1"> Cliente
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="material">Material</label>
    <input type="text" name="material" value="<?= @set_value('material') ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: acero,cobre" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alto">Alto</label>
    <input type="number" name="alto" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ancho">Ancho</label>
    <input type="number" name="ancho" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="largo">Largo</label>
    <input type="number" name="largo" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen">Imagen Referencia</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" required=''>
  </div>



  <center><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary"></center>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function insert(){

  $post = $this->input->post();
  $this->load->model('file');
  $file_name = $this->file->UploadImage();
  $post['file_name'] = $file_name;

  $bool = $this->cotizacion->insert($post);
  if($bool){
     header("Location: " . base_url() . "profile"); 
  }else{
    header("Location: " . base_url() . "article/nuevo"); //no se guardo
  }

  }
```

model file.php

```
            public function UploadImage(){

            $config['upload_path']          = './public/img/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view("/clientes/nuevo", $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

                     $file_name = $file_data['file_name'];
                     return $file_name;
            }
    }
```

please help where is the error  ?

Comment: Instead of this ```header("Location: " . base_url() . "profile");```, you can write ```redirect("/profile");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you add in form tag

Send form-data encoded as "multipart/form-data":

File upload documentation  [click here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
<form name="form_cot" action="<?php echo base_url('article/insert')?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for ="tipotrabajo">Tipo de Trabajo: </label>
 <input type="radio" name="tipotrab" value="0" required> Fabricación
 <input type="radio" name="tipotrab" value="1"> Reparación
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <label for ="origenmat">Origen del Material: </label>
 <input type="radio" name="origenmat" value="0" required> Empresa
 <input type="radio" name="origenmat" value="1"> Cliente
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="material">Material</label>
    <input type="text" name="material" value="<?= @set_value('material') ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: acero,cobre" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alto">Alto</label>
    <input type="number" name="alto" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ancho">Ancho</label>
    <input type="number" name="ancho" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="largo">Largo</label>
    <input type="number" name="largo" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen">Imagen Referencia</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" required=''>
  </div>



  <center><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary"></center>
</form>
```